# "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" Importing Android Sample project on Titanium Studio

Tags: android, linux

I`m running Linux 32 bit on virtual machine on a Windows 7 64 bit. Inside the Linux box I installed Java 7, latest Android SDK for Linux 32 bit and Titanium Studio. I gave read and write permissions to all three folders above. I would like to know what is causing this error "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when I try to import a sample project.

```
[INFO] logfile = /usr/Titanium_Studio/RSS Reader/build.log
[INFO] Building Sample.RSS for Android ... one moment
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 2.1.2 (08/24/12 14:46 ed7f777)
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.2.GA/android/builder.py", line     2237, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 1848, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.wait_for_device('e')
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 362, in wait_for_device
[ERROR]     devices = self.sdk.list_devices()
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.2.GA/android/androidsdk.py", line 220, in list_devices
[ERROR]     (out, err) = subprocess.Popen([adb, 'devices'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
[ERROR]     errread, errwrite)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1239, in _execute_child
[ERROR]     raise child_exception
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: new user tip: you should really ASK the question, even if it looks for you obviously. Statements like "I have error, like this, any advice appreciated" do not make people wanting to answer you :)